# Word doc print from Excel Error Named argument not found

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

```
Dim WA As Object, WD As Object
    Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set WD = WA.Documents.Add(Filename)
    With WD
        .PrintOut Copies:=1, _
             Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, Preview:=False
    End With
WD.Close False
WA.Quit False
Set WD = Nothing
Set WA = Nothing
```

I get error "Named argument not found", only works

> .PrintOut Copies:=1

But it show me a warning about wrong document margings

a reference in my project by clicking "Tools" ---> "References..." and then clicking the checkbox next to "Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library". Selected

No of  [this parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840681.aspx) working
So how Printout with all i needed parametrs?

Comment: Word's `Printout` method doesn't have `IgnorePrintAreas` or `Preview` arguments - why do you think you need them?

Comment: it show me a warning about wrong document margings, so which arguments have word's Printout method?

Comment: Look it up. ;) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837331.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Ok write the answer i will accept thanks? and what about marging warning? how just print document without any warnings
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word's `Printout` method doesn't have `IgnorePrintAreas` or `Preview` arguments. There's a list of the available arguments here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837331.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You may be able to suppress the margin warning using:

```
WA.Displayalerts = 0
WD.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
WA.Displayalerts = -1
```

Comment: But warnings still appears

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to stop that then.